# Using SendMessage to change the text in the foreground window obtained by GetForegroundWindow changes only the title, not the text inside the window

Tags: c#, .net

When I am using SendMessage for any process which is found by FindWindowEX then it's working fine and I am able to send text to particular application.

When I am using the GetForegroundWindow to find a window and trying to send text then it's not working. It's setting the title text rather then sending text into window.

could you please help me to resolve it, have a look on below code

```
//using FindWindowEX  
Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");  
FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, "testing");

//Using GetForegroundwidow  
IntPtr child = GetForegroundWindow();(0), "Edit", null);  
SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, "testing");
```

Comment: Use Spy++ to check what control each IntPtr handle actually refers to and you will be able to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the `WM_SETTEXT` message to a top-level window changes the title. If you want to change the text inside the window, you need to perform application-specific operations. (Different applications manage their contents differently.)

Comment: Thanks for help, could you please suggest me how can I perform application-specific operations to update text inside?

Comment: By definition, it is application-specific. For example, if it is Internet Explorer, you use the IHTMLDocument intefface.